# spring-kafka: Use Interactive queries in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

What's an «idiomatic» way of configuring (providing host and port info) and accessing Interactive Queries in Kafka Streams + Spring Boot application?

What's the correct way to access `KafkaStreams` instance to access the state stores?

I'm aware of `InteractiveQueriesService` in `spring-cloud-stream` but I wasn't to use just `spring-kafka` library with Spring Boot.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Boot auto-configures Kafka Streams support: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-kafka-streams.

The infrastructure underneath is hidden in the `StreamsBuilderFactoryBean`.
See Spring for Apache Kafka docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.6.2/reference/html/#streams-spring

So, you indeed can get access into that spawn `KafkaStreams` instance using API `StreamsBuilderFactoryBean.getKafkaStreams()`.

There is no high-level support for Interactive Queries, but probably having access to that `KafkaStreams` instance, it should not be so hard for you to go ahead with state stores interaction. Looks like that `InteractiveQueryService` is just a delegation to `KafkaStreams`.

Comment: hi Artem. your answers are always appreciated. just created a small POC https://gist.github.com/gAmUssA/69d4d6da2cf06b5015b3514f14a8e210. the main concern is how to access `KafkaStreams`. I'm trying to inject it to RestController but during rest controller initialization KafkaStreams instance may not be available. so I use `EventListener` to update the instance after the context is refreshed. it works but looks like hack to me. Coudl you suggest a better/idiomatic way to do it?

Comment: Yes, you can't do `streamsBuilderFactoryBean.getKafkaStreams()` from the ctor, just after injection. That internal `KafkaStreams` instance is initialized from the `start()` phase later on. I don't see a big problem to use that `streamsBuilderFactoryBean.getKafkaStreams()` from your `getValue()` REST method. Or you can initialize it "on demand" manner via some `private` method... On the other hand your `@EventListener(ContextRefreshedEvent.class)` is OK, too. Since it is really a point when we have `StreamsBuilderFactoryBean` started already.